# Git command to get latest commit of default branch

Tags: git, github

I am looking for a Git command to get the latest commit information of the remote default branch, the same information that Github shows you on the repo page just above the files.

the command:

```
git log -1 origin/branch_name
```

gives me the information I want however say I do not know the branch_name for the default branch and need to get that?

Comment: Git does not have a concept of a default branch. You will have to check the GitHub API if there is a call you can make to get the branch that's configured as default on GitHub

Answer (score 2):

If by default you mean `HEAD` on the remote (usually link to master) `git log -l origin/HEAD`

Comment: In my case I would like to know the latest commit to the default branch which is a release branch.

Comment: What defines the "default branch" or "release branch"?

Comment: If you look at a project on Github, you can click settings > branches and there you can set the default branch. However Fredrik mentioned above that Git has no concept of default branch, it's strictly a Github thing and maybe the Github API is a better option. Perhaps he's right but I'm asking because I don't know.

Comment: in your remote repo (GitHub or other), HEAD is a symlink or symbolic ref to your default branch. So origin/HEAD would be your default branch